# Bittorrent protocol 'not available'/'end connection' response?

Tags: ruby, udp, bittorrent

I like being able to use a torrent app to grab the latest TV show so that I can watch it at my lesiure.  The problem is that the structure of the protocol tends to cause a lot of incoming noise on my connection for some time after I close the client.  Since I also like to play online games sometimes this means that I have to make sure that my torrent client is shut off about an hour (depending on how long the tracker advertises me to the swarm) before I want to play a game.  Otherwise I get a horrible connection to the game because of the persistent flood of incoming torrent requests.

I threw together a small Ruby app to watch the incoming requests so I'd know when the UTP traffic let up:

http://pastebin.com/TbP4TQrK

The thought occurred to me, though, that there may be some response that I could send to notify the clients that I'm no longer participating in the swarm and that they should stop sending requests.  I glanced over the protocol specifications but I didn't find anything of the sort.  Does anyone more familiar with the protocol know if there's such a response?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If a bunch of peers on the internet has your IP and think that you're on their swarm, they will try to contact you a few times before giving up. There's nothing you can do about that. Telling them to stop one at a time will probably end up using more bandwidth that just ignoring the UDP packets would.

Now, there are a few things you can do to mitigate it though:

1. Make sure your client sends stopped requests to all its trackers. This is part of the protocol specification and most clients do this. If this is successful, the tracker won't tell anyone about you past that point. But peers remember having seen you, so it doesn't mean nobody will try to connect to you.
2. Turn off DHT. The DHT acts much like a tracker, except that it doesn't have the stopped message. It will take something like 15-30 minutes for your IP to time out once it's announced to the DHT.

I think it might also be relevant to ask yourself if these stray incoming **23 byte** UDP packets really matter. Presumably you're not flooded by more than a few per second (probably less). Have you made any actual measurements or is it mostly paranoia to wait for them to let up?

I'm assuming you're playing some latency sensitive FPS, in which case the server will most likely blast you with at least 10-50 full MTU packets per second, without any congestion control. I would be surprised if you attract so many bittorrent connection attempts that it would cause any of the game packets to be dropped.